# How to accommodate new logics that needs to be part of the ap

Tags: algorithm, oop, design-patterns

My scenario is
  I have API .
           which performs tday is function CompleteFlow() with some business logics like Step1() ,Step2().

Tomorrow in addition to function A there could be another logic like Step3() needs to be called.

and then Step4() .and so on..

So in general.

```
Class A
{

CompleteFlow()

}


CompleteFlow()
{
Step 1(),
Step 2().
....
....
....
}
```

Like wise in my sequence, new  businees logics can be added in the future. I need to write a UI client agains thease classes.

What is the best design pattern that suits me. (pls with examples)

Comment: Can you just mention how your steps would look like?

Comment: It is un related to previous step.. each is isolated step and it will not know what is the previous step is.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to abstract out every step and make sure it implements a contract specified by a common interface. And collect all the steps objects in a container and your CompleteFlow should have to call every step objects in the container sequentially. When you want to add a new step, just implement a new class and add an object of the same into the steps container.

Or you could have your step classes register themselves with the workflowsteps containers. So that container is completely independent of steps. Good design insists for loose coupling. So, depending on the need, you could modify the classes.

As per your comment, I see the order of calling steps is essentially sequential. Otherwise, you may have to implement a state machine or a workflow engine.

And providing concrete use cases, may help us to give bit more specific answers for your queries.

```
  class IStep {
      public:
         virtual void execute() = 0;
  };

  class ConcreteStep1 : public IStep {
       public:
          void execute() {
             cout << "Doing Step1";
          }
  }

  vector<IStep> workflowSteps;
  workflowSteps.push_back(new ConcreteStep1());
  // Add other steps like this.

  void CompleteFlow() {
      for (vector<IStep>::iterator it = workflowSteps.begin() ; it != workflowSteps.end(); ++it)
         (*it)->execute();
  }
```

Comment: It is sequential . can ypu please put up some dummy classesand interface so that i can visualize it completely.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the Chain of Responsibility, so the UI Client call will be something like this:

```
UI Client -----> Call Step1() // Suppose if you want to restrict the call to Step1(),
                              // pass some parameters in UI Client which you can handle
                     |        // in function calls
                     |        
                     V        
                 Call Step2()  // Otherwise pass the call to the next
                     |         //handler Step2().   
                     |
                     V
                  ......
```

In this way you can control your function call from the UI Client, that whether it should stop in a particular step or continue executing the next step function. Hope this helps.
You can also refer to the link : [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_patter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)n which explains chain of responsibility.

Comment: Ok. But the question is today i know step1() requess the parameter A.So i will pass the parameter A. But Say if my step2() requires paramter B then how will i pass the parametr from UI to this?

Comment: Suppose you pass 3 as value of one parameter from UI function, and you place the condition check as in each function(Step1, Step2, Step3) for the parameter value. In Step3 check if value ==3 then stop chaining it to the next handler and stop the execution. In this process, Step1, Step2, Step3 will be executed. I am just giving a vague example in this reason, you may chose to represent a differnt parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

You could abstract away all the step into a step chain. The step chain will be a reusable class so it's not specific to one class. In your case class `A`.

Create an interface for ordered steps to be executed in order by the step chain.

```
public interface Step {
    public void execute();
}

public interface Ordered {
    public int getOrder();
    public void setOrder(int order);
}

public interface OrderedStep extends Step, Ordered {
}
```

The comparator to help sort the instances implementing ordered.

```
public class OrderedComparator implements Comparator<Ordered> {
    public int compare(Ordered a, Ordered b) {
        if (a.getOrder() > b.getOrder()) {
            return 1;
        }

        if (a.getOrder() < b.getOrder()) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The step chain will be responsible for executing all steps in the specified order.

```
public class OrderedStepChain {
    List<OrderedStep> steps = new ArrayList<OrderedStep>();

    public void addStep(OrderedStep step) {
        steps.add(step);
    }

    public void execute() {
        Collections.sort(steps, new OrderedComparator());

        for (OrderedStep step : steps) {
            step.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

A simple implementation of a step.

```
public class OrderedStepImpl implements OrderedStep {
    public int order;

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Step#" + order + " executed");
    }
}
```

With all the steps handled by the step chain it's fairly easy to use. It's also easier to add this functionality into other classes that may require it.

```
public class A {
    OrderedStepChain stepChain = new OrderedStepChain();

    // add steps backwards
    public void createSteps() {
        for (int i = 9; i > 0; i--) {
            OrderedStep step = new OrderedStepImpl();
            step.setOrder(i);
            stepChain.addStep(step);
        }
    }

    /* 
     * Other objects may interact with the step chain
     * adding additional steps.
     */
    public OrderedStepChain getStepChain() {
        return this.stepChain;
    }

    public void completeFlow() {
        stepChain.execute();
    }
}
```

When I ran the unit test the output was.

```
Step#1 executed
Step#2 executed
Step#3 executed
Step#4 executed
Step#5 executed
Step#6 executed
Step#7 executed
Step#8 executed
Step#9 executed
```

Comment: Tying step order to the step lowers re-usability of a step

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer Thank you for the pointer. Adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my pseudo-code in Java:

```
public class Input
{
    public Map<Object,Class> data;
    public Input ()
    {
        data = new TreeMap<Object,Class>();
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface Step
{
    public void execute (Input in);
    public void revert ();
}
```

---

```
// Map<StepID, <Step, StepPriority>>
public class StepChain
{
    Map<Long, Pair<Step,Long>> chain;

    public StepChain ()
    {
        chain = new TreeMap<Long, Pair<Step,Long>>();
    }

    public void addStep (Long stepId, Step step, Long stepPriority)
    {
        chain.put(stepId, new Pair<Step,Long>(step,stepPriority));
    }

    public Queue<Step> getStack ()
    {
        Stack<Step> stack= new Stack<Step>();
        Map<Step,Long> map = new TreeMap<Step,Long>();

        for (Pair<Step,Long> p : chain.getValues())
        {
            map.put(p.getFirst(), p.getSecond());
        }

        for (Step step : map.getKeySet())
        {
            stack.push(step);
        }

        return stack;
    }
}
```